# Change the height of a JComboBox?

Tags: java, swing, jcombobox

Is there a way I can increase the height of the `JComboBox`?

I tried the following but the height doesn't seem to change anything.

```
comboBox.setBounds(100, 50, width, height);
```

Comment: See [How to Use Combo Boxes: Providing a Custom Renderer](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/combobox.html#renderer). Extra space can be added to the renderer by setting the insets or a margin or an empty border (as appropriate), but the best way to make a bigger renderer is to use a bigger font or icon.

Comment: You need to post a [mcve]. Is the `JComboBox` editable? What is the [layout manager](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/index.html) of the container that is the parent of the `JComboBox`? Are you referring to the `JComboBox` itself or to the drop-down list?

Comment: What do you mean by the height? The height of `JComboBox` control is usually the same as of `JTextField`. The height of the popup that opens when you click the drop-down button depends on the number of elements in the list.